# Why entity changed its state without explicit call to save method?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've the following piece of pseudocode:

```
Bid update(Bid toUpdate) {
  final Bid existing = repository.findOne(toUpdated.id); // 2

  if(existing.hasTerminalStatus()) {
    throw new WhateverException("Editing terminated bid is not possible!");
  }

  // ...

  closeCorrespondingBids(existing.saleOffer.id);

}

void closeCorrespondingBids(Long saleOfferId) {
  final List<Bid> bids = repository.findBySaleOfferId(saleOfferId);
  bids.forEach(bid -> {
    bid.status = CLOSED;
    update(bid); // 1
  });
}
```

When from the line marked with `// 1` the code returns to `update` method in `// 2` status is already changed even though no call to `save` was executed and no transaction if explicitly defined. Why is that?

In project spring boot v. `1.5.6.RELEASE` is used along with hibernate `5.2.11.Final`.

Is *dirty checking* the reason of the described behaviour?

Comment: yes. within a transaction, `onFlush` all entities in the session get dirty-checked and `UPDATE` statements get executed if the entities are dirty.

Comment: @msparer, thanks! I've no explicit transaction defined here. Is any default set?

Comment: I suppose you're using spring-data, then yes: "the CRUD methods of the Spring Data JPA repository implementation are already annotated with @Transactional" (from https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/)

Comment: @msparer, yes indeed `spring-data` is used in the project. Thanks for the link! What may be the solution here?

Comment: actually, `final Bid existing = repository.findOne(toUpdated.id); // 2` doesn't do anything except getting the same object (`==`) from the session, so you could just as well leave this call out and do the operation on the object directly

Comment: It seems that with current design I need to _detach_ this entity :/